# How to use UITextView delegate when there are three UITextViews in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview, xib

**Creating the UITextViews**

```
//Text View 1  
textview1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
textview1.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
textview1.delegate = self;

UIToolbar* doneToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
doneToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
doneToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(donedescButtonClickedDismissKeyboard)],
    nil];
[doneToolbar sizeToFit];
textview1.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar;

//Text View 2
textview2.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
textview2.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
textview2.delegate = self;

UIToolbar* doneToolbarmeasure = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
doneToolbarmeasure.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
doneToolbarmeasure.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(donemeasureButtonClickedDismissKeyboard)],
    nil];
[doneToolbarmeasure sizeToFit];
textview2.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbarmeasure;

//Text View 3
textview3.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
textview3.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
textview3.delegate = self;

UIToolbar* doneToolbarreportdesc = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
doneToolbarreportdesc.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
doneToolbarreportdesc.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(donereportdescButtonClickedDismissKeyboard)],
    nil];
[doneToolbarreportdesc sizeToFit];
textview3.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbarreportdesc;
```

**Delegate and Method**

```
-(void)donedescButtonClickedDismissKeyboard
{
    [textview1 resignFirstResponder]; 
}

-(void)donemeasureButtonClickedDismissKeyboard
{
    [textview2 resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)donereportdescdamageButtonClickedDismissKeyboard
{
    [textview3 resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
     textviewlbl1.hidden = YES;
     textviewlbl2.hidden = YES;
     textviewlbl3.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if(textview1.text.length == 0)
    {
        textviewlbl1.hidden = NO;
    }

    if(textview2.text.length == 0)
    {
        textviewlbl2.hidden = NO;
    }

    if(textview3.text.length == 0)
    {
        textviewlbl3.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

**Problem**

When I click on a UITextView all three labels are hidden, on second click all three are unhidden.
I need them to be hide and unhide them separately. Please Help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use same delegate method for all three textview like

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
  if (textView == textview1) {
    // Code for textview1
  }
  else if (textView == textview2) {
    // Code for textview2
  }
  else if (textView == textview3) {
    // Code for textview3
  }
}
```

So your method will be like :

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if(textView == textview1 && textview1.text.length == 0)
    {
        textviewlbl1.hidden=NO;
    }
    if(textView == textview2  && textview2.text.length == 0)
    {
        textviewlbl2.hidden=NO;
    }
    if(textView == textview3  && textview3.text.length == 0)
    {
        textviewlbl3.hidden=NO;
    }
}
```

Like this you can access all delegate methods of textview. Just differentiate textview by its object. Some other delegate methods are :

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView;
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView;
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange;
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithTextAttachment:(NSTextAttachment *)textAttachment inRange:(NSRange)range;
```

Comment: Perfect your code work.. Thank You Very Much @Pushkraj

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
 {
    if(textView.text.length == 0)
    {
       textView.hidden=NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your textview length is zero then you want to hide it or not?

Comment: when it length == 0. I want to show label. I dont to hide textview.

Comment: Your textViewDidEndEditing is called ? If yes then please check condition is matching or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use `if-condition` like this,

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
      if (textView == textView1) {
       }
     if (textView == textView2) {

       }
       // and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting `tag` to `UITextView`

In your `viewDidLoad` method set tag:

```
textview1.tag=1;
textview2.tag=2;
textview3.tag=3;
```

and now you can hide and show placeholder label by `if-else` condition

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (textView.tag==1)
    {
        textviewlbl1.hidden=YES;
    }
    else if (textView.tag==2)
    {
        textviewlbl2.hidden=YES;
    }
    else if (textView.tag==3)
    {
        textviewlbl3.hidden=YES;
    }
}
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (textView.tag==1)
    {
        if(textview1.text.length == 0)
        {
            textviewlbl1.hidden=NO;
        }
    }
    else if (textView.tag==2)
    {
        if(textview2.text.length == 0)
        {
            textviewlbl2.hidden=NO;
        }
    }
    else if (textView.tag==3)
    {
        if(textview3.text.length == 0)
        {
            textviewlbl3.hidden=NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The delegating object is the parameter of every delegate call, `textView` in your case:

`- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (textView == textview1)
    {
        // work with textview1 here
    }
    else if (textView == textview2)
    {
        // work with textview2 here
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
textview1.tag=1;
textview2.tag=2;
textview3.tag=3;
```

Give these three textview a tag that identify the different textview.

Comment: So the delegate's event likes below  
`- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if(textView.tag == 1)
    {
        
    } 
   if(textView.tag == 2) {}
   if(textView.tag == 3)
}`